# how to implement jquery load on scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

I have got a page in which I'm getting a users all friends posts now I want to get only 15 post first and then get I wanna add a load more button and then load 15 more posts how should I do that.

This is  my code

```
  $query =  "SELECT ph.likes, ph.image_url,ph.email,ph.username,ph.uid ,ph.id
          FROM photos as ph
          inner join followers as fol
          on fol.user_id = ph.uid
          where fol.uid = '$id'
          ORDER BY ph.image_url DESC ";
$fire = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
if (mysqli_num_rows($fire)>0) {



  while ($users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)) {
    $likes = $users['likes'];
    $username = $users['username'];
    $uid = $users['uid']; 
    $pixid = $users['id'];

     }

}


?>

<?php


$query =  "SELECT ph.ext, ph.likes,ph.desccription, ph.image_url,ph.email,ph.username,ph.uid ,ph.id,ph.avatar_path
          FROM photos as ph
          inner join followers as fol
          on fol.user_id = ph.uid
          where fol.uid = '$id'
          ORDER BY ph.image_url DESC ";
$fire = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
if (mysqli_num_rows($fire)>0) {



  while ($users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)) {
    $likes = $users['likes'];
    $description = $users['desccription'];
    $username = $users['username'];
    $uid = $users['uid']; 
    $pixid = $users['id'];
    $avatar_path5 = $users['avatar_path'];


    ?>


<div class="all" >
<div class="card" >
  <div class="float" >
  <div class="avatar" >
    <img src="<?php echo $avatar_path5; ?>" width="100%" class="avatar">
  </div>

      <div class="username" style="font-weight: 600; size: 14px;  text-decoration: none; color: black !important; ">
      <p style="color: black !important;"><?php echo "<div><a href='users?id=".$users['uid']."' style='color: black !important; '>
               <h3>".$users['username']."</h3>

      </div></a>"; ?></p>
</div>
</div>
   <?php
   if ($users['ext']=='mp4') {
     ?>
     <video class="videos"  controlsList="nofullscreen nodownload" style="width: 100%; height:100%;" controls autoplay="true" muted> 
 <source src="<?php echo $users['image_url']?>" type="video/mp4">

          </video>  

<?php
}else{
  ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $users['image_url']?>" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;">
  <?php }
  ?>
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b><?php echo "<div><a href='users?id=".$users['uid']."'>

      </div></a>";?></b></h4>

  </div>

  <div style="padding: 2px; margin-top: 5px;">
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['liked'])) {
    $postid = $_POST['postid'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE id=$postid")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
    or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $n = $row['likes'];

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO likes (user_id,username, post_id,avatar_path) VALUES ($id, '$fullname', $postid,'$activeavatar')")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE photos SET likes=$n+1 WHERE id=$postid")or die(mysqli_error($con));

    echo $n+1;
    exit();
  }
  if (isset($_POST['unliked'])) {
    $postid = $_POST['postid'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE id=$postid")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $n = $row['likes'];

    mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM likes WHERE post_id=$postid AND user_id=$id")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE photos SET likes=$n-1 WHERE id=$postid")or die(mysqli_error($con));

    echo $n-1;
    exit();
  }
?>
          </div>      
             <script type="text/javascript">
             $('video').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":in-viewport")) {
        $(this)[0].play();
    } else {
        $(this)[0].pause();
    }
})  
             </script>   
      <div>

        <?php 
          // determine if user has already liked this post
           $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE user_id=$id AND post_id=".$users['id']."")or die(mysqli_error($con));

          if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1 ): ?>
            <!-- user already likes post -->
            <span class="unlike fas fa-heart "   data-id="<?php echo $users['id']; ?>"></span> 
            <span class="like hide far fa-heart"    onclick="PlaySound()" data-id="<?php echo $users['id']; ?>"></span> 
          <?php else: ?>
            <!-- user has not yet liked post -->
            <span class="like far fa-heart"  onclick="PlaySound()" data-id="<?php echo $users['id']; ?>"></span> 
            <span class="unlike hide fas fa-heart "   data-id="<?php echo $users['id']; ?>"></span> 
          <?php endif ?>
<a class="com"  style="color: #929292 !important; " href="show?post_id=<?php echo $users['id'];?>" style="">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment trigger" ></span>comments</a>
<div class="wink" style="  color: black;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: 209px;
" > <?php  




?></div>
<div class="float2">
  <div class="react2" id="react2" data-rowid="<?php echo $pixid?>"><?php
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM gormint where post_id = $pixid and user_id= $id3";
$fire2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM bhai where post_id = $pixid and user_id= $id3";
$fire3 = mysqli_query($con,$query3) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
$query4 = "SELECT * FROM famer where post_id = $pixid and user_id= $id3";
$fire4 = mysqli_query($con,$query4) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
$query5 = "SELECT * FROM muskan where post_id = $pixid and user_id= $id3";
$fire5 = mysqli_query($con,$query5) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
if (mysqli_num_rows($fire2)>0) {
  echo "<img src='gormint.jpg' class='gormint2' style='width:30px; height:30px;'  >";
}elseif (mysqli_num_rows($fire3)>0) {
  echo "<img src='bhai.jpg' class='bhai2' style='width:30px; height:30px;'>";
}elseif (mysqli_num_rows($fire4)>0) {
  echo "<img src='famer.jpg' class='bhai2' style='width:30px; height:30px;'>";
}elseif (mysqli_num_rows($fire5)>0) {
  echo "<img src='bancho.jpg' class='bhai2' style='width:30px; height:30px;'>";
} else{
  echo "<img src='wink.png' class='wink2' style='width:30px; height:30px;'>";
}?>
</div>

<div class="flipClass" style="display: flex;" data-rowid="<?php echo $pixid?>" id="flip">react</div>


<div class="panelClass" style="" id="panel" data-rowid="<?php echo $pixid?>"> 
  <input type="image" onclick="PlaySound2()" id="display" data-value="<?php echo $users['id'];?>"  src="gormint2.jpg" class="close2 display gormint animated bounceIn " >
              <input type="image" onclick="PlaySound3()" data-value="<?php echo $users['id'];?>" data-rowid="<?php echo $pixid?>" id="display2" src="bhai.jpg" class="close2 display2 bhai animated bounceIn">
              <input type="image" data-rowid="<?php echo $pixid?>" onclick="PlaySound4()" data-value="<?php echo $users['id'];?>" id="display3" src="famer.jpg" class="close2 display3 bhai animated bounceIn">
              <input type="image" onclick="PlaySound5()" data-value="<?php echo $users['id'];?>" id="display4" src="bancho.jpg" class="close2 display4 bhai animated bounceIn">

              </div>

              </div>
              <div class="count2 ">
              <span id="count" style="margin-top: -5%;" class="likes_count"><?php echo $users['likes']; ?> likes</span><?php
              if ($description=='') {
                echo "";
              }else{ echo '<p style="margin-bottom: 5%" class="written"> <b>'.$users["username"].'</b>   '.$description;'</p>';
            }
              ?>

            </div>
             <form method="POST"  action="" >
                <div class="commentdiv">
                  <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" class="id" value="<?php echo $pixid;?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username"  value="<?php echo $activeusername;?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid"  value="<?php echo $id3;?>">
          <textarea style=""  name="comment" id="comment" class="comment"  placeholder="  comment here"></textarea>
         <button type="button" style="background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #3897f0; font-weight:600;" class="submit" id="button_id">comment</button>

       </div>

          </form>
        </div>
         <div id="comments">
            <?php



$sql = "SELECT * FROM comment where post_id='$pixid' limit 3";
$results = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($results)>0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $commentid = $row['id'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $string = covertHashtags($comment);
    echo "<p class='written'>";
    echo "<a href='users2?id=".$row['user_id']."' style='color:black !important;'><b>".$row['username']."</b></a>";
    echo "  ".$string;
     $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM comment where id ='$commentid' and user_id='$id' order by comment desc limit 5 ";
$results3 = mysqli_query($con,$sql3);
     if (mysqli_num_rows($results3)>0) {

      echo "<div class='dropdown'>
  <img src='ellipsis.png' class='dots'>
  <div class='dropdown-content'>
    <br><p  class='delete' data-delete=".$commentid.">delete</p>
  </div>
</div>";

    } 
    else{
      echo "";
    }

     echo "</p>";  


  }
}else{
  echo "";
}

            ?>

          </div>
      </div>
      <br><br>



    <?php } ?>
```

now what should I do to add a load more button after first 15 posts and when user clicks on that button I want to load more 15 posts and there is also one more problem I have a set a refresh functionality through j query whenever a user clicks on like button or comments the page refreshes so would this cause any problem?

Comment: you should use LIMIT and OFFSET on server side, and ajax call on scroll reach page end like 70- or 80 %  on client side.

Comment: can u please link any example @DevsiOdedra

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but the way you've written your SQL strings is incredibly unsafe. You should never directly put variables into your SQL string, especially if they're un-sanitised, and ESPECIALLY when those variables are coming straight from an external source such as GET or POST data. If you do, you're wide open to [SQL injection attacks](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). I strongly suggest reading up about about using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to help protect against this.

Comment: all the items which are in a get or post method are sanitised @JonWyatt

Comment: @dhruvsunoly No they aren't. There are many examples in your code. `$postid = $_POST['postid'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE id=$postid")or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: well these ids does not have any use in url so they are safe from sql injections@JonWyatt

Comment: no use in a GET var, nothing stopping me injecting SQL via POST though is there?

Comment: Whether or not they get used in your URL (whatever that is) has nothing to do with the prevention of SQL injection. Your code currently says "take this piece of information that was posted to me and directly use it as part of my SQL string". Anyone could post that value as anything they like, and in doing so manipulate the SQL that actually gets executed in unintended ways. I'm not going to go into further detail on this since I've already provided the relevant material to help you understand and fix it. If you choose to ignore it and pretend your safe, that's up to you.

Comment: So if I post postid as `1"; DROP TABLE photos;` then the query would be `SELECT * FROM photos WHERE id="1"; DROP TABLE photos;`

Comment: thanx ill fix this problem @JonWyatt

Comment: Look into mysqli or PDO, re: fixing injection.  @devsiOdedra why would you ever wanna handle pagination server side when avoidable?  Unless you have a dire need to update every event, ask once hold the data and do the pagination client side.  It's more responsive and saves your server a whole lotta load.